# Add message error to response body in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey

I have this endpoint:

```
    @POST
    @Path("login")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response doLogin(LoginCredentials loginCredentials) {
        try {
            usersService.validate(loginCredentials);
            return Response.ok().build();
        } catch (InvalidCredentialsException e) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        } catch (NotAuthorizedUserException e) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }
    }
```

In the `UNAUTHORIZED` cases, I want to send a message to specify the concrete error. How can do that?

In case where response is `ok`, I do that:

return `Response.ok("Some message here").build();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the entity(Object data) method:

```
Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity("Some message here").build();
```